# Navigating second time causes "cycle detected in merged resource dictionaries" exception

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am experiencing a very weird problem using Merge Dictionaries in my windows phone app. I navigate to secondary page (page1) from my MainPage, with a very simple button click

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

First time navigating goes correct. A second time (back and click button again) gives me an error "cycle detected in merged resource dictionaries". I created a very simple page and can reduce the problem just by adding the MergedDictionary + resourcedictionary. My Page1.xaml is the following:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins\Page1Skin.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I have a tiny mistake in my XAML. The backslash in the path to the ResourceDictionary must be a forward slash.

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins\Page1Skin.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Replacing it solved my problem. No clue why phone fails with this error!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for necroposting, but this topic is only one in whole web search which talking about this issue on WP8.0 (Silverlight).

Solution above didn't help me, so I found another one:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyProject.WP;component/Styles/MyPageStyles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Where:

1. "MyProject.WP" - my main project. This is name of it in a Solution.
2. "Styles" - folder in the solution.
3. ";component" - keyword for referencing on Assemblies.

In this case also you can select styles from another projects, just need to change Project Name in Source.